# How to get last specific document inserted in a MongoDB in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm quite new to MongoDB and Java and I need to do a very easy query: get last document of an object inserted in a collection. If I use the mongo shell I use `$last` and then I put the `key value`and timestamp field to get last document but using java driver (3.0.4) I found nothing about `last` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not rely on MongoDB always returning documents in insertion order. MongoDB does not guarantee that it will stay consistent. When a collection gets fragmented through deletes and updates, it can happen that MongoDB inserts a new document somewhere in the middle.

As an alternative solution you can sort your results descending by a timestamp field or by _id (auto-generated ObjectID's begin with the timestamp they were created at). A descending index can greatly improve the performance for this.

By the way: When the reason you do this is because you want to do something with a document you just inserted within the same process, then this might be a very fragile solution. When multiple processes insert documents at the same time, one process might get the document inserted by a different one. When you want to insert a document and maintain a handle so you can change the same document later, consider assigning an `_id` manually in Java by creating a [`new ObjectID()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html). You can then use that ObjectID to refer to the document later.

Comment: Sorry I didn't written that I have also a field named timestamp where I save the date